# Precisa de advérbio após «eis-me», «eis-te» etc.?

Tags: pronomes

O advérbio (*sic*) *eis* pode se ligar a um pronome pessoal: «ei-lo aí! quem estávamos procurando!», «Eis-me aqui, táxi». Eu, porém, só soube disso por leitura, então, não sei responder se é correto falar, mesmo que soe estranho,

> «Ei-lo!», «Eis-me!», etc.

Eis a minha pergunta: é correto dizer apenas «eis-me», «eis-te», «ei-lo» sem advérbio adiante?

Comment: "Sós", queres dizer se tem obrigatoriamente de vir seguido de *aqui, aí, ali*? *Ei-lo! quem estávamos procurando!* conta como só?

Comment: Então é fácil. Eu explicitaria era isso na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [dicionário Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/eis/) e o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/eis/14873) dizem apenas que *eis* pode ser reforçado com *aqui, aí* ou *ali*; não dizem que tem de ser. E em particular *ei-lo, ei-la* sem *aqui* nem *ali* são-me bastante familiares. Naturalmente, o pronome tem de se referir a algo mencionado antes ou a seguir. Temos um exemplo no Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa (2001):

> **eis** […] *Eis a noiva, ei-la!*

Exemplos da Literatura:

> […] anunciaram a chegada dele. Vem vindo! **Ei-lo!** Saltou lesto de um landô.
> [José Soares de Melo, *História da oração aos moços*, 1974.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=yjAsAAAAYAAJ&q=ei-lo&dq=ei-lo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTpvaJqr30AhXBB50JHU97A9AQ6AF6BAgSEAI)
>
> Conselheiro — Depois tudo te contarei. É teu noivo. Não tarde aí. (*Fernando Aparece*) **Ei-lo.**
> [*Teatro de Artur Azevedo*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=bGItAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%C3%A9%20teu%20noivo%20n%C3%A3o%20tarde%20a%C3%AD%22&dq=%22%C3%A9%20teu%20noivo%20n%C3%A3o%20tarde%20a%C3%AD%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGjfTQ1b30AhUN4YUKHUmbDZ4Q6AF6BAgCEAI)
>
> E **ei-la**, a morte! e **ei-lo**, o fim!
> [Olavo Bilac, *Antologia Poética*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZvbcRL_FsjQC&pg=PR37&dq=%22ei-la%20a%20morte%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkqYCy1r30AhULxoUKHYKCCzEQ6AF6BAgSEAI#v=onepage&q=%22ei-la%20a%20morte%22&f=false)

Com as outra pessoas gramaticais não me soa tão familiar, mas encontrei *eis-me:*

> Deixaram-me sozinho com Silvestre, enquanto se preparavam para a emergência.
> —***Eis-me***—suspirou.
> [Mia Couto, *Antes de nascer o mundo*, 2009](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MpcqAQAAIAAJ&q=eis-me&dq=eis-me&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_6quN1730AhWD0eAKHbJcC3cQ6AF6BAgJEAI)
>
> Minha terra: **eis-me**,
> Poeta sendo, rei sou
> [Revista do Instituto Histórico e Geográfico de Minas Gerais, 1961](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EWmfAAAAMAAJ&q=eis-me&dq=eis-me&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH7_q91730AhUQA2MBHRdkDgA4FBDoAXoECA8QAg)

Bastante comum sem *aqui, aí, alí*, é quando vem seguido de uma descrição qualquer do estado da pessoa ou do que ela está a fazer. Exemplo do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002):

> **eis** […] *tantos anos depois, eis-nos envelhecidos e enfraquecidos*

Outros exemplos:

> **Eis-me** a teus pés, oh Christo!
> [Cândido de Figueiredo, *Quadros Cambiantes*, 1867](https://books.google.pt/books?id=R64RAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA164&dq=%22eis-me%20a%20teus%20p%C3%A9s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqzJK72730AhUD8hQKHeD0AuwQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22eis-me%20a%20teus%20p%C3%A9s%22&f=false)
>
> E **eis-me** chegado, ao menos no domínio vocabular, ao campo do mais recente ensino deste Instituto […]
> [Estudos de ciências políticas e sociais, 1967](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hJgdAAAAIAAJ&q=eis-me&dq=eis-me&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH7_q91730AhUQA2MBHRdkDgA4FBDoAXoECAoQAg)

Portanto parece-me que o *aqui, ali*, etc. serve mesmo só para reforçar ou por uma questão de eufonia: simplesmente *Procuravas-me? Eis-me!* soa um bocado brusco. O Mia Couto escreveu simplesmente *eis-me*; mas o Mia Couto é o Mia Couto.